# Load Google+ Comments onload event

Tags: javascript, comments, google-plus, blogger

I use Google+ Comments system in my blog.

I wonder if there's a way to make it work as in Youtube.
To load when you scroll to the bottom of the page, not to load when the page is open.

That's the code that works now in blogger:

```
<div class='g-comments' data-first_party_property='BLOGGER' data-viewtype='FILTERED_POSTMOD' data-width='743' expr:data-href='data:blog.canonicalUrl'/>
```

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: In theory you should be able to do that with the `explicit` value of `parsetags` in the [JS API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#configuration_options) but you'll have to experiment with it since the comments widget is a private API.